# Odoo14 Action Server Error - Unable to Call Python Method Correctly

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14

I am facing an issue while trying to define an action server in Odoo14. The objective is to call a Python method that returns a window action because I need to access fields in the current model and pass them to the context. Unfortunately, directly using a window action with a context that calls fields doesn't seem to be working as expected. Below is the code snippet I am using:

**XML Code:**

```
<field name="name">Créer un paiement</field>

<field name="model_id" ref="account.model_account_bank_statement_line"/>

<field name="binding_model_id" ref="account.model_account_bank_statement_line"/>

<field name="state">code</field>

<field name="binding_view_types">list</field>

<field name="code">action = model.action_payment_bank_statement_line()</field>
```

**Python Method:**

```
def action_payment_bank_statement_line(self):
        action_ref = 'account.view_account_payment_form'
        print(action_ref)
        action = self.env['ir.actions.act_window']._for_xml_id(action_ref)
        action['context'] = {
            'default_payment_type': 'outbound',
            'default_partner_type': 'customer',
            'default_ref': self.payment_ref,
            'default_amount': self.amount,
            'default_date': datetime.strptime(self.date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        }
        action['view_mode'] = 'form'
        action['target'] = 'new'
        return action
```

However, I'm encountering the following error when I click on action button:

```
   result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 696, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 370, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 358, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 919, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 544, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1728, in run
    result = action.run()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 632, in run
    res = runner(run_self, eval_context=eval_context)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_actions.py", line 61, in _run_action_code_multi
    res = super(ServerAction, self)._run_action_code_multi(eval_context)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 501, in _run_action_code_multi
    safe_eval(self.code.strip(), eval_context, mode="exec", nocopy=True)  # nocopy allows to return 'action'
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 347, in safe_eval
    raise ValueError('%s: "%s" while evaluating\n%r' % (ustr(type(e)), ustr(e), expr))
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 652, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 317, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: <class 'AssertionError'>: "" while evaluating
'action = record.action_payment_bank_statement_line()'
```

I would appreciate any assistance in identifying and correcting the issue in the code, or any alternative suggestions for defining the action server correctly.

Comment: Why is there a comma in `action['view_mode'] = 'form',` and the following line at the end?

Comment: Thank you for catching that oversight. The commas were included by mistake, However, even after removing them, I'm still encountering the same error

Comment: you're using `model.my_method()` in your action code. That will lead to a empty recordset in `self`. Use `record.my_method()` instead or if the action is used in a list view `records.my_method()`.

Comment: Tried records.my_method() and also record.my_method(), still getting the same error

Comment: Please look into the odoo server log, to find out what the real error is.

Comment: Kindly review the updated question, where I've included the content from the Odoo server log

Comment: Okay, that's not helpful :-O can you try to use your method without the `context` part? I guess something is wrong with those 3 `self` uses.

Comment: I've used an action server only to be able to call the fields of the current model, which is why I've employed a Python method involving "self.". Are there any other alternative solutions to consider?

Comment: That should work, i've made a lot of them in various odoo versions up to odoo 16. My problem here: i can't debug your code and only can guess where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with how the action values were returned into the Python method. Here is the updated code:

```
def action_payment_bank_statement_line(self):
        view_id = self.env.ref('account.view_account_payment_form').id
        ctx = {
                      'default_payment_type': 'inbound',
                      'default_partner_type': 'customer',
                      'default_ref': self.payment_ref,
                      'default_amount': self.amount,
                      'default_date': datetime.strptime(str(self.date), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
              }
        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'res_model': 'account.payment',
                'target': 'new',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'views': [[view_id, 'form']],
                'context': ctx
        }
```